# Output number of children in a structure

Tags: structure, children

In my template I'm displaying all entries of a structure: ('areas').level(1) using a loop.

I would also like to display the number of children entries in each of the 'areas'.

Like: "Area 1, 4 properties", "Area 2, 7 properties", "Area 3, 5 properties" and so on.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the descendent too you can use:

```
{% set totalDescendents = entry.getDescendants().count() %}
```

https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getDescendants

Answer (score 1):

You could get the number of direct children using this:

```
{% set numChildren = entry.children().count() %}
```

I'm not sure if there's an efficient solution to getting the full number of children, grandchildren etc. without just comparing against the URL which seems like a workaround.